# class SQLite3 not found

Tags: apache2, php, sqlite, sqlite3

After struggling through a lot of pages and answers i am still unable to use sqlite with php. i am using fresh install of Ubuntu, Apache 2, SQLite3 and Php5.

I am still getting class SQLite3 not found error, please help me out.
I have done :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2    
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5    
sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite    
sudo apt-get install sqlite
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo apt-get install sqlite3`. It is different from `sqlite`.

Comment: @Fabby Thanks. I'm still convinced that it is the correct answer, short as it is. I have come across the same error myself. If the OP indicates that it does **not** solve his problem, I'll delete the answer and go hide under a rock.

Comment: @RPi_Awesomeness No offense taken. It is as simple as that: there are two distinct packages, that should not be confused.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem. It turned out that I had two different versions of PHP installed (7.0 and 7.2).  One version had the corresponding SQLite3 module, and the other didn't.

Once I got everything cleaned up, and only one version of PHP running, with the SQLite3 module, everything worked.